# "No multipart config for servlet" 500 error when spring.http.multipart.enabled=false and use instead Apache Commons File Upload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I need to upload a large file in stream mode to a server with Spring boot and embedded Jetty. When I use default org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile, I receive "Heap space exception" [Java heap space when uploading large file to server Spring boot with embedded Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936467/java-heap-space-when-uploading-large-file-to-server-spring-boot-with-embedded-je).

So I tried using Apache Commons File Upload instead of org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile.

```
@PostMapping("import/upload")
public void importUpload(
        @RequestParam("file")
        HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(zipArchive.getFile())) {
        FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                InputStream inputStream = item.openStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

For this, I turned off

```
spring:
   http:
     multipart:
       enabled: false
```

in application.yml

But now when I try to upload a file I get

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse
>   multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet  at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:112)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   ru.factorts.module.web.filter.SessionDetaildFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionDetaildFilter.java:24)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at ru.factorts.fesb.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:22)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:536)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1592)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1296)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1211)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2322)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2310)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:92)
>     ... 105 more java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for
>   servlet   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2322)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2310)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:375)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:112)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   ru.factorts.module.web.filter.SessionDetaildFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionDetaildFilter.java:24)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at ru.factorts.fesb.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:22)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:536)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1592)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1296)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1211)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:59)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `commons-file-upload` is incompatible on a Servlet 3.0+ environment.  Do not use it.

Comment: "I need to upload a large file in stream mode to a server with Spring boot and embedded Jetty." , using mime/multipart is not a streaming mode upload.  Multipart behavior in the Servlet API is blocking until the entire multipart declaration is received, and THEN you can read it.   If you want streaming mode, you'll have to send the file without multipart and/or any other form or parameter based technique.

Comment: For starters remove the `@RequestParam` from your controller and just use the `HttpServletRequest`. Also please specify which Spring Boot version you are using as the parameter to disable fileuploading has changed between versions. Finally you can still use Commons File upload with a `MultipartFile` just add a bean named `multipartResolver` and of type `CommonsMultipartResolver`. When configured properly it will cache on disk instead of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use this notation @MultipartConfig in your servlet?

```
@WebServlet(name = "fileUploadServlet", urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
@MultipartConfig(location=/tmp,
             fileSizeThreshold=0,    
             maxFileSize=5242880,       // 5 MB
             maxRequestSize=20971520)   // 20 MB
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```

Something like this. [Here](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-file-upload-example-using-multipartconfigelement/) you can see other options.

Comment: As I understand from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782026/springboot-large-streaming-file-upload-using-apache-commons-fileupload and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-apache-file-upload notation @MultipartConfig not needed, should work without it. I I tried adding `@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/server")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,  // 10 MB
        maxFileSize=1024*1024*5000,       // 50 MB
        maxRequestSize=1024*1024*10000)
public class ServerCtrl implements ApplicationContextAware` , but get same error. I cannot change controller to servlet ann.

Comment: I see. Adding this to your request changes something? `MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement((String)null);
request.setAttribute(Request.__MULTIPART_CONFIG_ELEMENT, multipartConfigElement);` for Jetty version > 9.

Comment: There's also the `WEB-INF/web.xml` version of the config declaration.

Comment: @LuckyMiv Reduce your `fileSizeThreshold`.  That determines the maximum size the file is allowed to be and be fully held in memory.   Any file received over that amount goes to disk in the `location` specified so that you use less memory.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thank you, I added spring.http.multipart.file-size-threshold=200MB  and the memory stopped loading using the default org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

Comment: @LuckyMiv that's the opposite of what I recommended. In fact I would recommend something below 100k.

Comment: Appreciate for clarification, I reduced the size